How to run an application as another user and then use that application to execute further commands in jenkins?
I want to run my .net tests in jenkins server. But they only run under a specific user. So, i am trying to run nunit3-console.exe for another user using runas command and then use nunit3-console.exe to run my tests that i am expecting to run under the same user i used to open nunit3-console.exe.
I tried writing these commands in jenkins Build steps:
echo 'password' | runas /netonly /user:Domain.net\username "C:\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.15.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe"
"C:\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.15.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe" "C:\test\Crm.Etoe.Tests\bin\Debug\ProjectTests.dll" --where "cat == category"
But they are failing.
